# Boot-repair won't install "unable to locate package"

Tags: 11.10, boot, dual-boot, live-usb

My computer won't boot so I am trying to install boot-recovery using the instructions from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. The initial command runs fine:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

but when I excecute the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

I brings up the following error

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package boot-repair
```

I am running a live USB on Ubuntu 11.10 if that makes any difference.
Thanks for the help

DeveloperNewb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The PPA](https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/boot-repair) has no version of boot-repair for Ubuntu 11.10, you should try it with a newer release of Ubuntu. Ubuntu 11.10 has no support from canonical anymore since [9 May 2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Table_of_versions) so it seems a good idea to upgrade anyway.

Comment: Ok, makes sense,I do have 12.04 LTS but I don't have a live CD for that... Thanks for the help.